# Plugin 220 adapter OK for higher amperage appliances?

Tags: electrical, 240v

I have used 220 volts from European outlets before via an adapter tool (it probably cost me 20 dollars and I probably have it around the house somewhere).  But that was only for limited uses like charging my cell phone, or my computer battery.

My wife's parents are visiting from Russia, and her mom wants to take home a rice cooker we have.  Obviously this uses more amperage.  Will this work OK when they get back to Russia?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the rice cooker's nameplate please?

Comment: Is there any possibility that this model of rice cooker is made in a 230V version for Europe/Asia/South America/etc.?

Comment: I've never been a fan of adapters for major appliances. Just my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which type of adaptor you are using.  There are some adaptors that just change the plug configuration (meaning, the profile of the prongs) and there are some adaptors that actually change the voltage and/or frequency of the power.

From the sounds of your "probably cost me 20 dollars"... you had an adaptor.  Each adaptor should be marked with its current capabilities.  **TYPICALLY** devices will use almost double the current when going from 220V to 110V - though *most* wall-wort (think laptop power brick) devices will accept 110-220 50/60hz and convert itself just fine because its an AC to DC converter.

All this being said, depending on the cost of the rice cooker it may not be worth buying the necessary transformer as its probably more cost effective to just buy the correct voltage one in the first place.